# Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter --- would have incorrectly overridden the package

Tags: java, android

I am using navigation `drawer activity android studio` and `Firebase Authentication`. When i going to run this app than i get this error.

```
  W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

I am also using least version SDK and build tool...

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
}
```

Comment: Is it a warning or an error?

Comment: Error. unfortunately stopping my App

Comment: did you find any solutions for this?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Android used to run on `Dalvik VM`.

`Dalvik` had a bug allowing classes to override parent's package-private methods.

So when they switched to `ART`, they fixed this, so it no longer overrides the parent's method, 
Now when such a scenario is detected, it logs a warning, making sure you're aware of the behavior change.

It seems that some `support-lib` classes (`PorterDuffColorFilter`, `VectorDrawableCompat`) have such scenario, so `ART` notifies you.

I think it's safe to ignore this, unless this is your own code, in which case I would either change the method's name, or test on Android running `Dalvik` (pre-4.1) and running `ART` (4.1+)

Comment: Note: [ART is only since 5.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime), and [`updateTintFilter` was also added in 5.0 (see tag list and commit date)](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/b3c56086d802ae28888dd97ba1f49bd6cee0b673#diff-92b9a3807d411843a83a062461322a924dc036c5110587266a697dfde74dce8dR1232). In my reading this means the warning for this method is a false positive, and 4.1 probably refers to when the Dalvik bug was fixed?