# Sometime app is perfectly installing and running in all versions of mobiles but sometimes it is showing App not installing Error

Tags: android, service

Here i am facing a problem like, Sometime app is perfectly installing and running in all versions of mobiles but sometimes it is showing `App not installing Error` Please help any one.

here i am using a toolbar in my activity.xml file like below is it effect my app in the above scenario.

```
    android:id="@+id/tlbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#5F9EA0"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop"></Toolbar>
```

Here is my log:

```
03-05 10:58:50.162 3718-3718/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system
03-05 10:58:50.162 3718-3718/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
03-05 10:58:50.162 3718-3718/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-05 10:58:50.273 3718-3718/com.example.lenovo.trainapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
03-05 10:58:50.472 3718-3731/com.example.lenovo.trainapp I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3169(275KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 28MB/28MB, paused 2.107ms total 162.384ms
03-05 10:58:50.861 3718-3736/com.example.lenovo.trainapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                           [ 03-05 10:58:50.863  3718: 3718 D/         ]
                                                                           HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb437b290, tid 3718
03-05 10:58:50.873 3718-3718/com.example.lenovo.trainapp D/Atlas: Validating map...
03-05 10:58:51.287 3718-3736/com.example.lenovo.trainapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-05 10:58:51.317 3718-3736/com.example.lenovo.trainapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xae834820: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
03-05 10:58:51.333 3718-3736/com.example.lenovo.trainapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae834820: ver 2 0
03-05 10:58:51.377 3718-3736/com.example.lenovo.trainapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-05 10:58:51.465 3718-3736/com.example.lenovo.trainapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae834820: ver 2 0
03-05 10:58:51.542 3718-3718/com.example.lenovo.trainapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 10:58:52.708 3718-3718/com.example.lenovo.trainapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Need more information than this.Be more specific.

Comment: i just updated my question please check it once

Comment: Can you show log here.

Comment: i updated my log above

Comment: Are you using any vector drawable in your project? . check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060702/before-android-4-1-method-android-graphics-porterduffcolorfilter-would-have

Comment: if i build every time and run, it is working fine but sometime i am forwarding the apk file through mail it is not installing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter --- would have incorrectly overridden the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060702/before-android-4-1-method-android-graphics-porterduffcolorfilter-would-have)