# launching error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

``I am a newbie to Andriod Studio. I am following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kufnu_q8MwA. I am using Android Studio 3.As part of this tutorial, I created two files and made some modifications on mainactivity.java.the application is launched successfully on my mobile. But I can only see the index page when I click on the link to open two.html. It is showing like "file doesnt exist.the file must have been renamed, deleted, or moved". 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String myurl="file:///android_asset/index.html";
     WebView view=(WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
     view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     view.loadUrl(myurl);


}
```

}

Logcat output

```
05-31 18:19:12.960 29333-29333/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-31 18:19:13.298 29333-29333/com.example.user.mywebapp I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
05-31 18:19:13.518 29333-29333/com.example.user.mywebapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-31 18:19:13.906 29333-29333/com.example.user.mywebapp I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 66.0.3359.158 (code 335915800)
05-31 18:19:13.958 29333-29333/com.example.user.mywebapp I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 3442-3444)
05-31 18:19:14.002 29333-29333/com.example.user.mywebapp I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(36)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
05-31 18:19:14.007 29333-29333/com.example.user.mywebapp I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "66.0.3359.158", actual native library version number "66.0.3359.158"
05-31 18:19:14.034 29333-29333/com.example.user.mywebapp I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
05-31 18:19:14.036 29333-29333/com.example.user.mywebapp I/cr_base: Android Locale: en_IN requires .pak files: []
05-31 18:19:14.224 29333-29406/com.example.user.mywebapp E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
05-31 18:19:14.230 29333-29399/com.example.user.mywebapp W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
05-31 18:19:14.233 29333-29406/com.example.user.mywebapp I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (Ib51f183a9b)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.02
    Build Date: 06/16/16 Thu
    Local Branch: 
    Remote Branch: 
    Local Patches: 
    Reconstruct Branch: 
05-31 18:19:14.304 29333-29415/com.example.user.mywebapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
05-31 18:19:14.320 29333-29333/com.example.user.mywebapp D/Atlas: Validating map...
05-31 18:19:14.394 29333-29406/com.example.user.mywebapp W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/evrc
05-31 18:19:14.395 29333-29406/com.example.user.mywebapp W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
05-31 18:19:14.397 29333-29406/com.example.user.mywebapp W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
05-31 18:19:14.407 29333-29406/com.example.user.mywebapp W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
05-31 18:19:14.408 29333-29406/com.example.user.mywebapp W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/evrc
05-31 18:19:14.414 29333-29406/com.example.user.mywebapp W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mpeg2
05-31 18:19:14.416 29333-29406/com.example.user.mywebapp W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mpeg2
05-31 18:19:14.424 29333-29406/com.example.user.mywebapp W/Utils: could not parse size range '64x64-1920X1080'
05-31 18:19:14.431 29333-29406/com.example.user.mywebapp W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mp4v-esdp
05-31 18:19:14.445 29333-29406/com.example.user.mywebapp I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
05-31 18:19:14.561 29333-29415/com.example.user.mywebapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-31 18:19:14.566 29333-29415/com.example.user.mywebapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
05-31 18:19:14.568 29333-29415/com.example.user.mywebapp I/qdutils: PartialUpdate status: Disabled
    Left Align: 0
    Width Align: 0
    Top Align: 0
    Height Align: 0
    Min ROI Width: 0
    Min ROI Height: 0
    Needs ROI Merge: 0
    Dynamic Fps: Disabled
    Min Panel fps: 0
    Max Panel fps: 0
05-31 18:19:14.669 29333-29333/com.example.user.mywebapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
05-31 18:19:14.684 29333-29404/com.example.user.mywebapp V/NotificationManager: com.example.user.mywebapp: cancel(10436)
05-31 18:19:14.695 29333-29333/com.example.user.mywebapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@272c4b48 time:513154182
05-31 18:19:14.700 29333-29422/com.example.user.mywebapp W/cr_CrashFileManager: /data/data/com.example.user.mywebapp/cache/WebView/Crash Reports does not exist or is not a directory
```

Please suggest. I am completely new to Android Studio. I know there is a small problem and I am unable to detect it. Thank you in advance.

```html
index.html

<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<button>
    <a href="two.html">
        <font size="30">go to second page</font>
    </a>
</button>
<center>this is first page</center>
</body>
</html>

two.html

<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<button>
    <a href="index.html">
        <font size="30">go to index page</font>
    </a>
</button>
<center>this is second page</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did u check the file is present or not?

Comment: Please provide the content of your index.html. Is your second file in the same folder as the index.html?

Comment: @TimRasim Thankyou for your reply.i provided my html code in question itself.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060702/before-android-4-1-method-android-graphics-porterduffcolorfilter-would-have

Comment: also make sure that your activity is declared in manifest file

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos   actually my Application is successfully launched on my mobile.the problem is i am getting only the first page i.e..,my index.html.i could not see my second page.is there any way i could check how many pages in my application are successfully launched?

Comment: Set a webViewClient with the shouldOverrideUrlLoading as described by Paraskevas answer and have a look how the url looks like when you click on the link (Either with a breakpoint or by logging the value). I would assume that the function should look like this:
view.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/ + url); but if url already contains "http://" you might need to replace part of the url.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
     if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent); 
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }   
});
```

And try to add in href full path of second page like: http://localhost/two.html