# Android : Not able to see the assembleRelease option in the Gradle Task window?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have recently migrated from Android plugin 2.14.1 version and gradle version  2.2.2
to 
4.10.1 and 3.3.1 respectively

But I observe that the assemble release option is now **NOT** present in the gradle window now.

I am observing a crash while calling a native library(Android plugin and Gradle version remains 2.14.1 ,2.x.x respectively.

[image]

crash log(informative) , the app **stucks** as a white window and nothing appears :

```
2019-02-27 11:04:24.822 11720-11720/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-02-27 11:04:24.884 11720-11720/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

Is it related to assemble release option in some way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter --- would have incorrectly overridden the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060702/before-android-4-1-method-android-graphics-porterduffcolorfilter-would-have)

Comment: @Zoe question is more about the missing assemble release portion than on the crash.

Comment: Check `Tasks -> other`

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך not there as well. I think it  depends on Gradle or Android Plugin version??? is it?

Comment: I still found it in `Tasks->other` for each module. I'm using gradle version `4.10.1` and android gradle plugin `3.3.1`